# Black Screen Problem after building using Unity hub

Tags: unity-game-engine

The black screen appears after I have built an AR app. Followed exactly from the tutorial video:(( I'm using Huawei P10 Lite, min API 8.0, AR foundation ver 4.0.2, AR core ver 4.0.4, Ar kit face tracking 4.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have ARCore installed on the device from the Google Play Store. I'm not sure if the Huawei device can access the Google service.

Comment: and since ArCore on play store supports android version 8.0 and above, I can't download it from my device :(